# Send contact information via Hangouts on Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: contacts, sms, samsung-galaxy-s-5, google-hangouts

I have a difficulty when trying to send contact information on Samsung Galaxy S5 mini. Setup:

- I have Google Hangouts as default SMS app.
- Android: 4.4.2 (KitKat)

Steps:

- Go to Contacts, long tap on the contact which information you want to share and press "Send contact information" from menu.

[image: Send contact information]

- Select fields to send (e.g. tap "Select all").
- Now when I press "Done", Android launches default SMS app which offers to become a default one. Without allowing it to become a default SMS app in place of Hangouts I cannot send the contact.

Expected: Default SMS app is not called to complete the action, but rather Hangouts is launched.

Note 1: I need to send SMS, not MMS with vCard attached.

Note 2: This functionality is known to work on Samsung Galaxy S4.